# Why did Mortal Kombat: Legacy S01E06 have a special notice added from the director in the start?

Tags: production, mortal-kombat-legacy

In Mortal Kombat: Legacy S01E06, we are introduced to the Raiden for the first time and as like other episode they molded origin story again. But this is the only episode with a note from director himself:

[image]

Why is it done like this and only to this episode specifically and not repeated again?
As the rest of the episodes are also a different take on the characters.

Comment: Was there anything visually or stylistically different about the episode that you could tell? Or does it seem pretty similar to most other episodes in the series?

Comment: @Thunderforge to me it appear same like any other episode

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All episodes up to that point had more or less stuck to the continuity established in the video game.  In this particular episode, Raiden is shown to be quite different than the character in the game.  He goes through many trials and tribulations, and emerges as a true God.  He's tortured, poked, prodded, humiliated and, eventually, killed, only to be reborn.  This all happens not at the hands of some opponent with a fierce uppercut or a sword, but rather at the hands of mortal men with syringes.  And still, he becomes the protector of the Earth.  That's a lot to swallow.